# Team Git workflow working with a multi-project Sitecore solution using TDS

Tags: git

We are a team of 8-10 developers working on different parts of a Sitecore instance. In the past we've used SVN and more recently (and successfully) Hg, but are moving to using Git as our primary source control. We're working with Sitecore 7, and using the latest TDS from Hedgehog. In case it matters we're also using the Glass.Mapper.sc lib from Mike Edwards.

The problem we're running into, especially compared to how easy it was with Hg, is that merges are a nightmare. It doesn't help that most of our team is new to Git, but most of us have at least used Hg so it's not a huge leap. We've had so many problems that we moved to a merge-master setup, where the team leads are handling all the merges.

My question is this: From people using these tools, what would you suggest is the best workflow and supporting configuration? A team member suggested rebasing to reduce conflicts, but that doesn't seem to matter.

Our Hg workflow, which worked very well was: 1) Commit local changes as many times as needed. 2) Pull changes from the server, and update to the remote branch after any merge. 3) Sync TDS. We do this after the pull so that we're not overwriting the .scproj file in the merge 4) Commit the merge and TDS sync 5) Push the results back to remote

We didn't have merge nightmares and tds was kept very clean. We tried to adapt something similar with Git and have wasted a lot of time each week to resolve issues.

We currently have each dev working in their own branch because of the merge errors working with everyone in master. The type of merge issues I'm seeing seem to mostly come from what Git merges automatically. I definitely don't want to merge everything by hand every time, but I wouldn't mind doing project file merges by hand. We're using Sourcetree and I have BeyondCompare Pro.

Any suggestions, especially coming from successful implementations, would be greatly appreciated. If there are simply config changes that can be made or a change to our workflow to make the process more reliable I'd love to learn about them.

Comment: (yes, P.SE is the right spot for this question - see [where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/)) Do you branch locally? or do you commit to your local copy of the 'mainline' and then merge?  How long is the period between the start of step 1 and the step 5?

Comment: What kind of problems did you have when you converted your Hg workflow? You can replicate that same workflow in git and "should" run into the same set of pains, rather than introducing new ones. Are people getting tripped up by the staging area model? i.e., where are those spurious merge problems coming from?

Comment: Just curious, what are advantages to switch to git over Hg? other than having a better git-bisect functionality?

Comment: @michaelT: We branch locally as needed, and we're working in our own branches and then merging up into a master branch. Since we have been having problems with merges, I've been merging other people's branches in (acting as merge-master) and then reverse integrating the main line into their branches. This isn't ideal, but for the time it was the only way we could ensure that merges were happening correctly. 1 to 5 has so far not gone more than a week at a time, and other than project, solution, and TDS project files, everyone is for the most part working on their own parts of the code base.

Comment: @Alex: The biggest problems are in the project files. We always had to be careful with Hg, but they're regularly blowing up with Git.

Comment: It was originally suggested by the only person on our team that had prior Git experience that we rebase whenever we would normally pull and merge in Hg. I've been doing a lot of reading on this, and I see there's a lot of argument about whether or not this is correct. Step one, I'm going to stop the rebasing and see if that resolves part of it. I found articles discussing a few TDS configuration changes and changes to the .gitignore that might also help. I'm going to try to get the workflow as close to what we did in Hg as possible, since the consensus is that the workflows should be the same.

Comment: @nobugs The biggest reason we're sticking with Git is due to industry acceptance. We work with clients and other consultants often, and while I personally prefer Hg and have used it successfully for years, it doesn't have the same industry presence that Git does, or even SVN for that matter as bad as it is.

Comment: @JonUpchurch -- Would you consider the project files to be 'derived'? I.e., could they be auto-generated as a post-fetch trigger rather than checked in?

Comment: @alex Possibly, and I'll look into that as an option. The only thing that worries me is that it's possible that that would be adding complexity when my goal is to reduce complexity. If it works however, I'll do whatever it takes.

Comment: You're trading one form of complexity for another, but it might be easier to centralize the work to maintain this new form.

Comment: @AlexFeinman That makes sense. I'll look into that and see if it's feasible. At the same time I'm going to try to get my workflow back as close to what we did in Hg, and hopefully it will make this process smoother. My goal is to get it back to a point that I don't have to act as merge master anymore.

Comment: The `git pull --rebase` workflow is brutally simple but avoids a lot of the hassle of merging - recommended at least until you have got to grips more with git.

Comment: I ended up starting again from ground zero. Our TDS projects had gotten a bit corrupted, so I regenerated them from my database. Once I got the solution cleaned up after the issues we had, the workflow that finally worked is this: I control our master branch. My team pulls and merges master into their own branches (choosing resolve using 'theirs' for anything TDS related). They complete the merge, and then sync their own TDS. Then they commit and push their changes to origin/Their Branch. I carefully integrate these pushes into master using the same process.

Comment: No one rebases (this seems to have been part of the problem) and I think people were a bit less careful about merging TDS before (which I have now enforced on pain of stern language). Merges back into master have been much simpler than before and so far it seems to be working. I've lost far less time to Git overhead than I was before.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a lot of things in this question I don't know about, but I feel like proper application of a `.gitattributes` file might solve many of the conflicts. http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html

For example, there are some files we have where people are always adding lines, rarely removing them. So a line in similar to `*.tds merge=union` can help take care of all the conflicts. Without understanding Sitecore and TDS a bit more I'm just guessing on your exact needs, but this hopefully should get you started down the right path.